# C# print number from for loop

Tags: c#

I want to display the number say 1 to 100 by selecting a item in drop down list. I mean, if I select 4 times, it should count as 4 and display.
I have tried the code below, but it is not working.

```
//Method
public void cl()
{
    if (Catddl.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Label12.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        }
    }
}

//called the method
protected void Catddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cl();
}
```

Comment: It is not really clear if you want to count the number of times user changes his selection in the dropdown, or count from 1 to the selected value and display that. Please clarify.

Comment: provide clear information with an example..

Comment: Aravind here you only want to show count in label or any thing else
Like if you select 2nd item then label text should be 2 or any thing else ?

Comment: Also the check should probably be `Catddl.SelectedIndex != 1`.  `0` is a valid listbox index

Comment: @Sunny : actually when we select the item from that the label should show the count. Example, Now i would select any item from the list at first time, then it shows 1, and second time it should shows 2, like that it should go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on your problem and this is the result.It works fine for me.Hope it also work for you.

```
 static int count = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bind();
    }
}

private void bind()
{
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    ar.Add("first");
    ar.Add("Second");
    ar.Add("Third");
    ar.Add("Four");
    ar.Add("Five");
    ar.Add("Six");
    ar.Add("Seven");
    DropDownList1.DataSource = ar;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string str = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    if (count == 0)
        count = 1;
    Label1.Text = count++.ToString();
}
```

Still if you have any doubt then ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to count how many times the user selects something from a drop down list, you can do:

```
int counter = 0;
private void Catddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    Label12.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The only way it is showing '1' is if you have int counter = 0 inside of the SelectedIndexChanged. If it is outside then it should work.

Comment: actually when we select the item from that the label should show the count. Example, Now i would select any item from the list at first time, then it shows 1, and second time it should shows 2, like that it should go